# Dependency Injection in .Net Azure Function Isolated Process

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

I have an Azure Function running .Net 7 isolated, including the latest stable versions of:

- Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions (1.1.0)
- Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker (1.10.1)
- Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk (1.7.0)

I am following this dependency injection guide specific to isolated functions, and am having some trouble getting it working:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#start-up-and-configuration

My `Program.cs` contains this for injecting the dependency:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s => 
    {
        s.AddSingleton<IMyInterface>(new MyConcreteClass(constructor args);
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

And then in the Azure function code:

```
public class MyAzureFunction
{
    [Function("MyAzureFunction")]
    public async Task RunAsync([ATrigger(
        ...TheTriggerArgs...
    )] IReadOnlyList<MyDataClass> input, IMyInterface myService)
    {
        myService.DoSomeWork(input); //exception is thrown here
    }
}
```

There are no compiler warnings in VS, but a null reference exception is thrown when the function executes the commented line.

The error is:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It seems the dependency injection is simply not working...

The exact same pattern and classes work fine for me in other apps like minimal API's and Blazor Apps, so I think this is something specific to Azure Functions?

If it makes any difference, I've also tried doing Azure Function dependency injection the "other" way (with a start method override) with the same result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this by adding the interface as a private property to the function class and creating a constructor which sets it using constructor injection.

I suppose that in web apps and other app templates it is doing this for you "in the background" - whereas in functions it does not.

program.cs is unchanged:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s => 
    {
        s.AddSingleton<IMyInterface>(new MyConcreteClass(constructor args);
    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Property and constructor added to the function class:

```
public class MyAzureFunction
{
    private readonly IMyInterface _myInterface;

    public MyAzureFunction(IMyInterface myInterface)
    {
        this._myInterface = myInterface;
    }

    [Function("MyAzureFunction")]
    public async Task RunAsync([ATrigger(
        ...TheTriggerArgs...
    )] IReadOnlyList<MyDataClass> input, IMyInterface myService)
    {
        myService.DoSomeWork(input);
    }
}
```

This works correctly and solved the problem.

Comment: I tried through private property and constructor but the value are retained till the middleware and not reflected those values in the below snippet of code of endpoint.  Faced the below mentioned error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Have you solved for the issue that if you set a breakpoint inside the ctor it'll get hit with *every* function execution? Seems like a massive perf hit if you ask me.